# Setting proxy server in Eclipse Mars

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration, config, configuration-files

I am using a server "http://abc/xyz.pac",port 80 to connect to internet in Internet Options. How do i configure the same in eclipse.

FYI, there are lot many multiple proxies in this pac file and they keep getting updated. so is there a way to directly apply this pac file onto eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Window > Preference > Network connections Select the "Native" as the "Active Provider". It will use pac file designated in IE to connect to Internet.